# Image doesnt upload to server when I try upload on client side. Im creating a crud website and ive done everything to send the image to the server

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express

```
    import axios from "axios";
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Link, useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import UploadedImage from "../uploadedImage/uploadedImage"

const Add = () => {
  const [pelicula, setPelicula] = useState({
    titulo: "",
    año: "",
    desc: "",
    genero: "",
    imagen: "",
  });

  const [imagenUrl, setImagenUrl] = useState (null)
  const [imagenData, setImagenData] = useState(null)
  
  const handleImageUpload = (e) => {
     setImagenData(e.target.files[0]);
  };

  // const handleImageInputChange = (e) =>{
  //   e.preventDefault();

  //   if(!imagenData){
  //     console.log("couldnt upload")
    
  //   return
  //  }
  //   const formData = new FormData();
  //   formData.append("imagen", imagenData);

  //   fetch('http://localhost:8800/upload', {
  //     method: 'POST',
  //     body: formData
  //   } )
  //   .then(res => res.text())
  //   .then(res => console.log(res))
  //   .catch(err => console.error(err)
  //   )

  //   document.getElementById('fileinput').value=null
  //   setImagenData(null)

  // }

    const  handleImageInputChange = async (e) =>{
    e.preventDefault();
    
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', imagenData);

    try {
        
        console.log('formData', formData);
        console.log('imageData', imagenData);

        formData.append('imageData',imagenData)
        const response = await axios.post('http://localhost:8800/upload', formData, {
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
  },
});
  

        if (response.status === 200) {
          const responseData = response.data;
  

          setImagenUrl(responseData.imagenUrl);
        } else {
          console.error('Fallo al subir imagen');
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('No puede subir imagen:', error);
      }
    };

    


  const [error, setError] = useState(false);

  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setPelicula((prev) => ({ ...prev, [e.target.name]: e.target.value }));
  };

  const handleClick = async (e) => {
    
    try {
      await axios.post("http://localhost:8800/movies", pelicula);
      navigate("/");
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
      setError(true);
    }
  };

  
  return (
    <div className="container mt-5">
      <div className="row justify-content-center">
        <div className="col-md-6">
          <h1 className="mb-4">Agregar película</h1>
          <form>
            <div className="mb-3">
              <input
                type="text"
                className="form-control"
                placeholder="Nombre"
                name="titulo"
                onChange={handleChange}
              />
            </div>
            <div className="mb-3">
              <textarea
                rows={5}
                className="form-control"
                placeholder="Descripción"
                name="desc"
                onChange={handleChange}
              />
            </div>
            <div className="mb-3">
              <input
                type="number"
                className="form-control"
                placeholder="Año"
                name="año"
                onChange={handleChange}
              />
            </div>
            <div className="mb-3">
              <input
                type="text"
                className="form-control"
                placeholder="Género"
                name="genero"
                onChange={handleChange}
              />
            </div>
            <div className="mb-3">
              <input
                type="text"
                className="form-control"
                placeholder="Portada"
                name="imagen"
                onChange={handleChange}
              />
            </div>
            <button
              type="button"
              className="btn btn-primary"
              onClick={handleClick}
            >
              Agregar
            </button>
            {error && <p className="text-danger mt-3">Something went wrong!</p>}
            <Link to="/" className="d-block mt-3">
              Ver todas las películas
            </Link>
          </form>
    <div className="mt-2 mb-2">
          <h2 className="text-center">Agregar imagen</h2>
            <form >
        <div className="input-group mb-3">
        <input id="fileinput" onChange={handleImageUpload}
        className="form-control"
          type="file"
          accept="image/*"
          
        />
        <button onClick={handleImageInputChange} className="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Agregar</button>
        </div>
      </form>
      {imagenUrl && <UploadedImage imageUrl={imagenUrl} />}
    </div>
          
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );

}
export default Add;

This is my react page(only the add movie one)

import express from "express";
import mysql from "mysql";
import cors from "cors";
import path from "node:path"
import fs from "fs/promises"
import multer from "multer";  
import { log } from "node:console";
import { dirname } from "node:path";
import { fileURLToPath } from "node:url";

const app = express();
app.use(cors())
app.use(express.json())
const port = 8800;
const router = express.Router()

const db = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    password: 'fifauefa',
    database: 'moviesdb',
})

db.connect((err) => {
    if (err) {
        console.error("Error al conectar a la base de datos:", err);
    } else {
        console.log("Conexión a la base de datos exitosa");
    }
});

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.json("Hello",)
})


app.get("/movies", (req, res) => {
    const q = "SELECT * FROM movies";
    db.query(q, (err, data) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return res.json(err);
      }
      return res.json(data);
    });
  });

app.post("/movies", (req, res) => {
    const q = "INSERT INTO movies(`titulo`, `año`, `genero`, `desc`, `imagen` ) VALUES (?)"
    const values = [
        req.body.titulo,
        req.body.año,
        req.body.genero,
        req.body.desc,
        req.body.imagen
    ]

    db.query(q, [values], (err, data) => {
        if (err) return res.send(err);
        return res.json(data);
      });
    });

app.delete('/movies:id', (req, res) => {
    const movieId = req.params.id;
    const q = 'DELETE FROM movies WHERE id = ?'

    db.query(q, [movieId], (err, data) => {
        if (err) return res.json(err);
        return res.json("Movie deleted successfully")
    })
})

app.put("/movies/:id", (req, res) => {
    const movieId = req.params.id;
    const q = "UPDATE books SET `titulo`= ?, `año`= ?, `genero`= ?, `desc`= ?, `imagen` = ? WHERE id = ?";
  
    const values = [
        req.body.titulo,
        req.body.año,
        req.body.genero,
        req.body.desc,
        req.body.imagen
    ]
  
    db.query(q, [...values,movieId], (err, data) => {
      if (err) return res.send(err);
      return res.json("Movie updated successfully");
    });
  });

  const __filename = fileURLToPath(import.meta.url);
  const __dirname = dirname(__filename);

  const diskStorage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: path.join(__dirname, './upload'),
    filename: (req, file, cb) => {
      cb(null, Date.now() + file.originalname);
    }
  });
  const fileUpload = multer({
    storage: diskStorage
  }).single('file')

  router.post('/upload', fileUpload , (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.file);
  })



app.listen(port, ()=>{
    console.log("Hello this is the backend server running on 8800")
})
```

this is my server.

I want to upload and display images but nothing ive tried has work so far.'
When I hit upload I get a 404.

AxiosError {message: 'Request failed with status code 404', name: 'AxiosError', code: 'ERR_BAD_REQUEST', config: {…}, request: XMLHttpRequest, …}

Would appreciate any help
Thanks in advance.